# One long running process per user in an ASP.NET Core Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, task, long-running-processes

I have an async function which will go and do some long running and CPU intensive task.  As it is async it doesn't hold up the UI.

Under normal conditions I have no problem with the way it runs.  The process is triggered on a button click, but it could be triggered on an API call.

I found that if I hit the button many many times in quick succession, the whole site starts to respond slowly.This is an abusive type of use but nevertheless it has a detrimental impact on performance.

I would like to implement a list in memory of calls to functions by user so that each user would be able to have a single instance the long running function running, but it would not accept any further requests from that user.

Who knows of some clever way of implementing this or has done something like that before.  I'm thinking of something like a threadsafe collection you can add tasks to, but if you try to .Add a task that is already running for a certain user / claimsprincipal, then it will fail to add it.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx Read this on why running **CPU bound** async tasks is a horrible idea in ASP.NET (also applies to ASP.NET Core)! Use async only for truly async operations, like I/O (File, Network) or Database connections. Never for CPU bound tasks. Doing CPU intensive stuff in a background thread or Task is only useful for UI development (WPF, Windows Phone application etc.) where the UI gets blocked if you run CPU intensive stuff on UI Thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without diving into the question of whether doing this is the right thing for your specific business situation and architecture, I see your question as basically boiling down to this: How can I ensure that a user can only invoke a particular process one at a time.

You could use a threadsafe collection to hold a flag for each user that indicates whether they are currently running such a process.  Use a try{}finally{} block in your async code to manage the value.  Set it to true inside the try block and set it to false in the finally.  The rest of your long running work comes after you set it to true and before you the finally is executed.  sketched out below:

```
try{
    //if thread safe value for this user is already true then exit.

    //set thread safe collection value for this user to true

    //Do work

 }finally{

     //set thread safe collection value for this user to false;
 }
```

If it were me, I'd put an object in the collection where the object has one value which was the bool.  That way I could use the `lock` keyword to hold a lock on the object for that user when I was checking it's value or setting it's value so that I could ensure that no other process changed the value between when I checked it and when I set it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is the type of response I was looking for.  Is there a way of having a collection of running tasks along with some identifier of the user that I can use to determine if that user has already got one of those tasks running so I can prevent them from issuing another while their current one is running.  Some sort of Dictionary<int,Task> or something like that? (int being userId)

Comment: Sure you could do that but there is really no need to put the task in the dictionary if you just want to know if one is running for the user.  Just put an object in the dictionary for the userId and in that object have a bool that you will set or clear as I outlined above.  This bool tells you if the user has a processing running or not. You could put the bool directly in the dictionary but the advantage of an object holding the bool is that you can lock the object while you check it's value and/possibly modify it's value.

Answer (score 4):

There are some issues with your solution:

1. If the task is CPU intensive it can still hold up the UI even when it is `async`. Once all CPUs are busy, you will see a performance impact.
2. Long running taks are not a good idea on a webserver. Webservers are designed to handle a large number of short requests. Long requests are not handled efficiently and they might also be recycled before they have completed.
3. Your implementation makes denial of service attacks easy. You basically have created one with clicking your button multiple times.

You should offload these kinds of tasks to an application server that is better suited to handle this kind of work. That keeps your webserver free to do what it does best: handle web requests.

Use the form of communication between web and application server that suits your needs best: WCF, a REST API or a message queueing framework such as MSMQ or RabbitMQ.

Comment: I hear you.  What I am trying to do though is stop malicous calling of a not-often used function from wasting resources.  Even if the task was run somewhere other than the webserver it would still potentially bring that other server to a crawl. The task is not that long running but if i click the button as fast as I can for about a minute (several clicks a second) it causes the performance problem.

Comment: Depending on your technology, the app server might be able to handle it. If, for example, your tasks are sent to a queue where old entries can expire, the app server will not get overloaded. It all depends on your requirements.

Comment: I am using Hangfire to run some light background tasks and its brilliant.  Tasks run in a few milliseconds typically so I am not misusing it.

Comment: Well, with hangfire you already have a framework to distribute your jobs to an app server. Use its capabilities first to handle your performance issues, before you do your own implementation.

Comment: I am on the same page as you with architecture.  What I was looking at though was a way to make the app not process the command at all if it was issued from the same user.  I want to stop it from processing it anywhere if its already been set off and is currently running.  Lets say we have a command  that is awaiting work from the database and we don't have any CPU work while we wait.  However we are trying to protect the database from unneccesary or duplicate work caused by some malicous button clicker like myself.  Would there then be a use for my idea?

Comment: This was a really good answer, this is exactly what I am going to do in a similar use case. I decided to build a REST API with a Checkout-Checkin mechanism. A scheduler that will hit an api of a service app every #interval and the service app will make a call to checkout the data from the core app, and check in processed data.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I implemented a Service as a Singleton that I registered with DI.

```
public class SingleInstanceRegisterService: IDisposable
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<SingleInstance,SingleInstance> dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<SingleInstance, SingleInstance>();
    AutoResetEvent arv;
    Timer timer;

    public SingleInstanceRegisterService()
    {
        arv = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        timer = new Timer(this.Cleanup, arv, 0, 60000);
    }

    public bool TryAdd(SingleInstance i)
    {
        return dict.TryAdd(i, i);
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(SingleInstance i)
    {
        return dict.ContainsKey(i);            
    }

    public bool TryRemove(SingleInstance i)
    {
        SingleInstance x;
        return dict.TryRemove(i, out x);
    }

    public void Cleanup(Object stateInfo)
    {
        AutoResetEvent autoEvent = (AutoResetEvent)stateInfo;

        if (dict != null)
        {
            foreach(SingleInstance i in dict.Keys)
            {
                if (i.Expiry < DateTimeOffset.Now)
                {
                    TryRemove(i);
                }
            }

        }
        autoEvent.Set();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        timer?.Dispose();
        timer = null;
    }
}
```

The SingleInstance is then defined as:

```
 public class SingleInstance: IEquatable<SingleInstance>
{
    public string UserSubject;
    public string FullMethodName;
    public DateTimeOffset Expiry;

    public SingleInstance(User u, MethodInfo m, DateTimeOffset exp)
    {
        UserSubject = u.UserSubject.ToString();
        FullMethodName = m.DeclaringType.FullName + "." + m.Name;
        Expiry = exp;
    }

    public bool Equals(SingleInstance other)
    {
        return (other != null &&
            other.FullMethodName == this.FullMethodName &&
            other.UserSubject == this.UserSubject);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        return this.Equals(other as SingleInstance);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (UserSubject.GetHashCode() + FullMethodName.GetHashCode()); 
    }
}
```

To use it we do the following.
_single is my dependency injected SingleInstanceRegisterService.

```
var thisInstance = new SingleInstance(user, method,   DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1));
if (_single.TryAdd(thisInstance))
{
    // tell the database to kick off some long running process
    DoLongRunningDatabaseProcess();
    // remove lock on running process
    _single.TryRemove(thisInstance);
}
```

If the TryAdd fails to add it then it must already be running.  Note that there is a timer that will automatically clear out process locks that have expired.